# Why can't I upgrade my train's capacity?

Tags: logis-tycoon-evolution

I've got a train in Warsow, and I want to have a bigger capacity. Why can't I upgrade it? As seen in the below screenshot, I've got just enough funds.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Not played the game - just guessing - but the speed and fuel both have extra blocks underneath the coloured bar. I'm thinking the white blocks are available upgrades while black is bought (you've upgraded the fuel on this once?). If I'm right then this particular vehicle doesn't seem to be able to upgrade it's carrying capacity any further. A glance at a screenshot on the play store (https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YTC5UyMUbT66zujzVmwzGtUsm7R5OP4eFXgq9QEVrtPhggN8l28243btPQa05e-Iuw=h900) shows other vehicles with different numbers of blocks, and therefore different upgrade options..?

Comment: Crap, you're probably right. I immediately upgraded it, because 8 tons is not quite good enough. I overlooked those little bars. You can submit it as an answer, if you'd like

Comment: http://www.quickmeme.com/img/b0/b00904c5e45abb06d12e540adad553a8df1fcca2f00e18f63d0135beb5c481ce.jpg - you can probably confirm if I'm right by upgrading the fuel a second time or trying a second vehicle. Don't mess up your game to do that though, I'll neaten the comment into an answer in short while.

Comment: Thought about checking it, indeed. But money is a bit scarce now, and speed isn't necessary, and fuel capacity is expensive (to max it). Looking forward for your answer (I'll be offline for some time, so I cannot accept it right away).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not played this game, so this is guesswork based on the fact that it's pretty likely the game shoes you what upgrades you can buy and already have bought.

If you look at the three stats bars - I'm going to call them cargo, speed and fuel - as well as the coloured bar (that I'm guessing is an indicator of how good the vehicle is in that stat) there are blocks underneath the bar. Given the single block under cargo is black, while there's white blocks on the other stats, I'm guessing that these blocks show the possible upgrades for the vehicle, with black being those you've already bought.

If I'm right, this means you've already bought the single available cargo upgrade for this vehicle.

Also, a glance at a screenshot taken from the Google Play store shows other vehicles with different numbers of blocks under each stat. Some of these blocks are already coloured though, which puts my "white blocks are available upgrades" into doubt...

[image]